# How to convert "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" to "MMM DD" and "HH:MM"?

Tags: android, timestamp

I am new in android. Now I am struggling with a time stamp. I will get data from api in the form "2014/10/31 00:49".. I need the format as "OCT 31" in one variable and "00:49" in an another variable. How can i solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks quite complicated, but suits your needs exactly:

```
// your input string
String dateInputString = "2014/10/31 00:49";
try {
    // obtain date and time from initial string
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", Locale.ROOT).parse(dateInputString);
    // set date string
    String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd", Locale.US).format(date).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
    // set time string
    String stringTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ROOT).format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // wrong input
}
```

`stringDate` : `OCT 31`

`stringTime` : `00:49`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , assuming current dat time

```
    Date today = new Date(); // current time

    String date[] = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(today).split(",");
    String month = date[0]; // get only date 
    String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(today); 
    // split the time if you need to remove PM/AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Timestamp tsTemp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(tsTemp);
System.out.println(currentTimeStamp);
```